# Gas stove burners won't light

Tags: stove

I have a Jennaire gas range (model SVD48600P).  The burners on the right won't light without a match.  I suspect it's the spark module or spark electrode because I don't see any spark when I try to light the burners on that side.  How do I know which is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried brushing the spark gap area with a toothbrush? All it takes is a piece of crud in there to prevent lighting.

Comment: Awesome - that did it!  A quick scrub with a toothbrush and a spray of electronics cleaner did the trick.  -- One tip:  make sure the electronics cleaner has fully evaporated before testing.  It's flammable and makes quite a show that does not please the wife.